# Tomcat startup failed in Netbeans

Tags: java, batch-file, tomcat, netbeans

I have an issue with Tomcat implementation in Netbeans, I am simply unable to start it from over there.
I am using Netbeans 8.0.2 and Tomcat 8, the instant I try to start it says Error starting of tomcat failed, **'127.0.0.1' is not recognized as an internal or external command**,
operable program or batch file. Now I have tried deleting the quotes from `catalina.bat` file because I heard that that will help but still nothing... Does anyone have some ideas? I would greatly appreciate it . Thanks.

P.S I am able to start it manually and everything runs fine, but I really need this to continue my development.

Comment: let's try to remove it from NB and then add new instance of server. also, if you are in Server tab, can you get the list of apps if click on `Web Applications` branch?

Comment: I have removed it multiple times already, but i did it again . This is how my services/server tab looks like http://i68.tinypic.com/wamtef.png, and this is my tomcat properties : http://i67.tinypic.com/28lf9dz.png

Comment: It's not running. Start it and then click to unroll `Web Applications`. The error must be displayed in pop-up window. If it is tell me the error.

Comment: As soon as i try to start the server this is what i get in the tomcat log http://i67.tinypic.com/r1wile.png and this error pops up : http://i63.tinypic.com/xophs8.png. I hope that this is what you have wanted.

Comment: well, this looks wierd. So, I can only advise: 1 - remove server; 2 - uninstall it from PC; 3 - delete all folders with all Tomcat servers on your PC; 4 - download Tomcat **7**; 5 - unzip on c:\ and configure all with your settings (do not use standard users for ex.) 6 - add that new tomcat base to your NB and try to Start.

Comment: The thing is, i have tried that already and also i have tried both 7 and 8, with windows installer and external variant. Maybe to reainstall whole netbeans?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Goto `Tools -> Options` and select `No Proxy` then `Ok`. Hope this will resolve your problem