# How to config and start a TomCat 7 with NetBeans 8

Tags: tomcat, netbeans, server, tomcat7, netbeans-8

I am trying to start a TomCat instance on my pc via netbeans for testing purpose... I first downloaded Tomcat 7.0.69 from the website, then extracted in my doc folder and created a new server inside NetBeans 8 (Tools -> Server -> Add Server). When I run the server I get this message:

> "127.0.0.1" non è riconosciuto come comando interno o esterno,
>    un programma eseguibile o un file batch.

Translated:

> "127.0.0.1"  is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

What's wrong? How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/37766761/5180017

Answer (score 2):

```
in bin/catalina.bat, change from
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% %LOGGING_CONFIG%"
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% %LOGGING_MANAGER%"
```

to

```
 set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% %LOGGING_CONFIG%
 set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% %LOGGING_MANAGER%
```

ref:https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=248182

Answer (score 1):

For apache-tomee-plume-8.0.0 i've modified catalina.bat :

from:

```
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% %JSSE_OPTS%"

rem Register custom URL handlers
rem Do this here so custom URL handles (specifically 'war:...') can be used in the security policy
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources"
```

to:

```
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% %JSSE_OPTS%

rem Register custom URL handlers
rem Do this here so custom URL handles (specifically 'war:...') can be used in the security policy
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
```